# Write function from SQL Server into MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have some problem to convert an SQL Server query into MySQL.
In SQL Server, the function recognize as `DATENAME()` and I changed it into `MONTHNAME()`. Then `dateadd()` in SQL Server become `date_add()` function.

Some sample for SQL Server query is

```
DATENAME("month",DATEADD("month",1,'8/1/2006'))
```

As I mentioned above, the query works well in SQL Server but it's not working at MySQL.

Then I tried rewrite the function into like this

```
MONTHNAME("8/1/2006",DATE_ADD("8/1/2006", INTERVAL 1 month))
```

Once again, it nots working.

How to fix that?

Comment: Firstly only tag the RDBMS you want your solution in.

Comment: added it,  rdbms tag

Comment: No, I meant don't tag SQL Server because you are not looking for SQL Server experts, you are looking for MySQL experts.

Comment: What does `MONTHNAME("8/1/2006",DATE_ADD("8/1/2006", INTERVAL 1 month))` give you and what do you want it to return?

Comment: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'MONTHNAME'

Comment: i want get month from the date and add it one month interval based the first argument. it like ex: august -> july 2006

Comment: @RicoAmanda MonthName() takes only one argument. You give them 2 arguments. That's why you get error.

Comment: yes i know. how to create function like that in mysql version?

Comment: because datename() in mysql not recognize

Comment: Try this:SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD('2006-08-01',INTERVAL 1 month));  date format should be entered as 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

there is easy way to solve my problem.

i just rewrite it again from

```
MONTHNAME("8/1/2006",DATE_ADD("8/1/2006", INTERVAL 1 month))
```

into this

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD("8/1/2006", INTERVAL 1 month), "%M")
```

this way, i get what i want

NOTE: THANKS FOR THE DOCUMENT MR P.SALMON